# my project laravel when i click submit in form with errors in input my view refresh multiple time so i can't see message errors

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, bootstrap-4

this problem exist in chrome and not exist in opera
this my view code here i try to do form with validate and div with type of errors:

```
@if(count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
<form action="add" method="POST">
{{ csrf_field() }} <!--Securite-->
    Product name <input type="text" value="{{ Request::old('name') }}" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('name') ? 'is-invalid' : ''}}" name="name" placeholder="enter product">
<br>
    Product Price <input type="text"  class="form-control {{ $errors->has('price') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" value="{{ Request::old('price') }}" name="price" placeholder="enter price">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Add Product">
</form>
@endsection
```

Comment: can you please do `{{ $errors ? dd($errors) : null }}` And post here what you got

Answer (score 1):

try this one .

this will be a function in your controller.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required', 
        'price' => 'required'
       
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('your-view-name')
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
    }

}
```

> ### Errors on view with foreach

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

> ### Your Form

```
<form action="{{url('/route-name')}}" method="POST">
@csrf
    Product name <input type="text" value="{{ Request::old('name') }}" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('name') ? 'is-invalid' : ''}}" name="name" placeholder="enter product">
<br>
    Product Price <input type="text"  class="form-control {{ $errors->has('price') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" value="{{ Request::old('price') }}" name="price" placeholder="enter price">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Add Product">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

> Use the code below in your blade

```
@if (count($errors))

    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
    @endforeach

@endif
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?